# Why doesn't rtcwake wake up the PC after suspend?

Tags: suspend

I'm putting an an Ubuntu device to sleep at 02:00 in the morning. I want to wake the device with `rtcwake` at 06:59 in the morning, but it does not wake up.

Command:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/rtcwake -m no -l -t $(date +\%s -d 'today 06:59')\n
rtcSet="$(sudo /usr/sbin/rtcwake -m show |grep -i on)"
if [[ $rtcSet != *on* ]];
then
sudo /usr/sbin/rtcwake -m no -l -t $(date +\%s -d 'today 06:59')
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the wake up issue by using service instead of rtc wakeup.

https://cmcenroe.me/2014/11/24/scheduled-suspend-and-resume-with-systemd.html